# what the standard pdf scale(Millimeters,centimeters,inches)?

Tags: file, pdf, document

i'm looking for write a special API to generate PDF, so... i'm using the text atributes/commands to build a pdf document through a simple text file.

I've already downloaded the pdf references manual, but i didn't found what i looking for.

What the standard pdf scale?

I need know the standard pdf scale to measure my line lenght, and change my width of "MediaBox".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **MediaBox**, **CropBox**, **BleedBox**, **TrimBox**, and **ArtBox** are rectangles expressed in *default user space units*, cf. Table 30 – Entries in a page object in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

The size of this unit is defined by another **Page** dictionary entry (cf. the same table):

> **UserUnit** number *(Optional; PDF 1.6)* A positive number that shall give the size of default user space units, in multiples of 1 ⁄ 72 inch. The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent. Default value: 1.0 (user space unit is 1 ⁄ 72 inch).

The **UserUnit** is only used very rarely. Thus, most of the time the unit you are after is 1/72th inch.

BTW, it is called ***default*** user space unit because in a content stream you can constantly change the size of a unit in user space by using appropriate changes of the transformation and/or text matrices; thus, in the context of content streams this 1/72th inch is merely a starting value.